# Update a Sagemaker Endpoint when changing the docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am looking for the simplest solution for updating a Sagemaker Endpoint. The only thing I want to change is the docker image (to update the code).

I am building the new Docker image on my computer, and then I upload it on ECR (I plan to do this in a CI/CD in the near future).

From my understanding, it seems that the simplest way is to create a new `EndpointConfig`, then call the `UpdateEndpoint` API to switch the endpoint to the new config, then delete the old `EndpointConfig`. Does anyone know a simpler way? Or can anyone confirm that this is the simplest approach to doing this?

Comment: did you get any better way to update the endpoint which can work quickly?

Comment: @N.Singh no, I still wish I could do this in a single API call

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: interesting, still no alternative

Comment: given that very few companies would use prebuilt models in prod, there is always the need to update the code, its wierd that they haven't implmented a way to do this. It is even harder when you use terraform to use UpdateEndpoint without using random names so that the endpoint updates eveytime.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use `boto3 sagemaker client` which has the [update_enpoint](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/update_endpoint.html) method.

Here is a pseudo code in python

1. first [create_model](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/create_model.html) with the updated `docker image`

```py
session = boto3.Session()
sm_client = session.client('sagemaker')

sm_client.create_model(
            ModelName = cfg.sagemaker.ENDPOINT_NAME,
            ExecutionRoleArn = ROLE_ARN,
            PrimaryContainer = {
                'Image': AWS_IMAGE_FULLNAME,
                'ModelDataUrl': MODEL_CLOUD_PACKAGE,
            }
        )
```

2. create a new [endpoint_config](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/create_endpoint_config.html)

```py
sm_client.create_endpoint_config(
                EndpointConfigName=CONFIG_NAME,
                ProductionVariants=[{...}],
            )
```

3. [update_enpoint](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/update_endpoint.html)

```py
sm_client.update_endpoint(
                EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                EndpointConfigName=CONFIG_NAME,
            )
```

Comment: This is a possible implementation of the strategy I described in the question (using boto3)